# XSLT: How to represent OR in key match

Tags: xslt

I have the input XML as

```
<document>
<item>
<gtin>4341</gtin>
    <functionalName lang="en">Filte</functionalName>
    <functionalName lang="en">test1</functionalName>
    <functionalName lang="chi">Filters2</functionalName>
    <functionalName lang="hin">Filters3</functionalName>
    <gtinName lang="en">gtinName1</gtinName>
    <gtinName lang="en">gtinName2</gtinName>
    <gtinName lang="hin">gtinName3</gtinName>
</item>
<item>
<gtin>4342</gtin>
    <functionalName lang="en">Filte</functionalName>
    <functionalName lang="chi">Filters</functionalName>
    <functionalName lang="en">Filters1</functionalName>
    <gtinName lang="en">gtinName1</gtinName>
    <gtinName lang="chi">gtinName2</gtinName>
    <gtinName lang="chi">gtinName3</gtinName>
</item>
</document>
```

I want to loop through each language and get the count with respect to group by of language

Expected output XML should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CatalogItem>
<RelationshipData>
  <Relationship>
     <RelationType>Descriptions_for_Item</RelationType>
     <RelatedItems count="3">
        <RelatedItem1 referenceKey="ITEM_DESCRIPTION-4341-en" />
        <RelatedItem1 referenceKey="ITEM_DESCRIPTION-4341-chi" />
        <RelatedItem1 referenceKey="ITEM_DESCRIPTION-4341-hin" />
     </RelatedItems>
  </Relationship>
</RelationshipData>
<RelationshipData>
  <Relationship>
     <RelationType>Descriptions_for_Item</RelationType>
     <RelatedItems count="2">
        <RelatedItem1 referenceKey="ITEM_DESCRIPTION-4342-en" />
        <RelatedItem1 referenceKey="ITEM_DESCRIPTION-4342-chi" />
     </RelatedItems>
  </Relationship>
</RelationshipData>
</CatalogItem>
```

Sample XSLT which is used by me but its not giving me expected Output

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="functional" match="gtinName" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', @lang)" />  

<xsl:template match="document"> 
<CatalogItem>
    <xsl:for-each select="item">
        <RelationshipData>
            <Relationship>
                <RelationType>Descriptions_for_Item</RelationType>
                   <RelatedItems count="{count(gtinName[generate-id() = generate-id(key('functional', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @lang))[1])])}">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="gtinName[generate-id() = generate-id(key('functional', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @lang))[1])]"/> 
                   </RelatedItems>
            </Relationship>
        </RelationshipData>
    </xsl:for-each>
</CatalogItem>
</xsl:template> 

 <xsl:template match="gtinName|functionalName">        
 <RelatedItem1 referenceKey="{concat('ITEM_DESCRIPTION','-',ancestor::item/gtin,'-    ',@lang)}"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "*I want to loop through tag "functionalName", "gtinName" for each language and get the count with respect to group by of language*" That's not what your output shows, is it?

Comment: Or did you mean count the languages in each item?

Comment: I want the count for each language

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I want to loop through each language and get the count with respect to group by of each language of each item.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the count of language attributes on either "functionName" or "gtimName" then change your key to this

```
<xsl:key name="functional" match="gtinName|functionalName" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', @lang)" />
```

Then, to get the count of the languages, do this

```
count((functionalName|gtinName)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('functional', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @lang))[1])])}">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="functional" match="gtinName|functionalName" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', @lang)" />  

<xsl:template match="document"> 
<CatalogItem>
    <xsl:for-each select="item">
        <RelationshipData>
            <Relationship>
                <RelationType>Descriptions_for_Item</RelationType>
                   <xsl:variable name="lang" select="(functionalName|gtinName)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('functional', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @lang))[1])]" />
                   <RelatedItems count="{count($lang)}">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="$lang"/> 
                   </RelatedItems>
            </Relationship>
        </RelationshipData>
    </xsl:for-each>
</CatalogItem>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="gtinName|functionalName">        
 <RelatedItem1 referenceKey="{concat('ITEM_DESCRIPTION','-',ancestor::item/gtin,'-    ',@lang)}"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As an alternative, if only "gtinName" and "functionalName" have a "lang" attribute, you could use the syntax `*[@lang]` instead....

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="functional" match="*[@lang]" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', @lang)" />  

<xsl:template match="document"> 
<CatalogItem>
    <xsl:for-each select="item">
        <RelationshipData>
            <Relationship>
                <RelationType>Descriptions_for_Item</RelationType>
                   <xsl:variable name="lang" select="*[@lang][generate-id() = generate-id(key('functional', concat(generate-id(..), '|', @lang))[1])]" />
                   <RelatedItems count="{count($lang)}">
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="$lang"/> 
                   </RelatedItems>
            </Relationship>
        </RelationshipData>
    </xsl:for-each>
</CatalogItem>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="*[@lang]">        
 <RelatedItem1 referenceKey="{concat('ITEM_DESCRIPTION','-',ancestor::item/gtin,'-    ',@lang)}"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```